# Intellisense autocomplete not working for wsl in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been setting up vscode as an IDE for python development. I use windows subsystem for linux with my python packages installed through anaconda there.

My problem is that auto completion does not work as expected. For examples, outside of wsl if I am using the numpy package I can get autocompletion:

[Autocomplete outside of wsl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qYqy.png)

However, inside of wsl autocomplete does not find numpy.linalg (as in example above):

[Autocomplete inside wsl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbucQ.png)

Thanks in advance!

edit: I am currently using wsl1 if that information is relavent!

Comment: ¿Have you installed the extension in WSL? ...Like this example: https://snipboard.io/X9p3Yn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Adriana Hernández](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6496248/adriana-hern%C3%A1ndez) you need to install the extensions inside WSL too.

The VSCode WSL docs are covering these [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_managing-extensions)

In short if you go to the extensions tab, you shall see Python marked with "Install in WSL...". Once clicked install and reloaded, it should work.
If not you likely need to pick another interpreter (likely the one from your venv.)

hit Ctrl+Shift+P then

- Python: Select interpreter
- then select the desired python interpreter (most likely the one in your venv which has all the packages)

What works for me is creating a venv, activating then launching VSCode from WSL with `code .`
On the first time you will need to install your extensions to WSL, but then it should be good to go.

Comment: All you mentioned is installed.

- extensions in local and WSL2
- switch to a different interpreter
I use conda virtual env, and no matter switch to anyone, it's still not working. 

Furthermore, it's working on another Ubuntu server I working with. I have checked and reinstalled all extensions and reset settings.json, making sure no difference between them, but it's still not work in WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, switch to clang extension - works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, inside the WSL Linux environment, the Python extension isn't installed. Open the extension tab within your wsl2 Linux Ubuntu environment and check for

```
Microsoft Python
```

there's an option to install Python for WSL Ubuntu Linux click install and that should solve the problem.